# C++ printf field width specifier ‘.*’ expects int not size_t

Tags: c++, printf

I'm in the process of fixing compiler warnings in a legacy project I inherited. New compiler is gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC).

Their is lots of code like the following:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

struct foobar
{
    char field1[10];
    char field2[5];
};

int main()
{
    struct foobar foo;
    memset(&foo, ' ', sizeof(foo));
    strncpy(foo.field1, "1234567890", sizeof(foo.field1));

    // Produces warning
    printf("[%.*s]", sizeof(foo.field1), foo.field1);

    return 0;
}
```

This produces a warning messages:

```
1_test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
1_test.c:16:49: warning: field precision specifier ‘.*’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("[%.*s]", sizeof(foo.field1), foo.field1);
```

This seems wrong to me  as '.*' SHOULD expect a size_t but apparently it doesn't...

Is there anyway to fix this problem globally besides having to do something like the following:

```
    // Fixes
    printf("[%.10s]", foo.field1);

    // Fixes
    printf("[%.*s]", static_cast<int>(sizeof(foo.field1)), foo.field1);
```

Comment: I was about to say "use `static_cast`" but you're right, that's an ugly solution.

Comment: @Slava It is not C++, but it is part of it

Comment: @KABoissonneault which part of code above makes it C++ but not C?

Comment: I would like to avoid language pedantry here. I'm compiling c++ code with g++. The example is the smallest program to show my problem.

Comment: Spec says must be `int`, so it's got to be an `int`. You could hide the conversion behind a function or macro or template it away, but what you currently  have has the advantage of being obvious, if wordy.

Comment: @Slava the scope of the solution includes c++ alternatives.

Comment: @Slava The answers. We have the right to know in which environment the code will be compiled. For example, now I know I can use `static_cast` instead of a C cast

Comment: @LeviX even if you use `g++` with .c file it compiles it in C mode.

Comment: @KABoissonneault file extension is .c so no you cannot use `static_cast`

Comment: @Slava When did 'C' get <cstdio> and <cstring>?  `MessageBox` is not C++ but that doesn't mean Windows users can't ask C++ questions if they're using Microsoft's libraries. Lastly, printf itself is used in the C++ standard numerous times, so does that make the C++ standard not C++?

Comment: @kfsone the fact that gcc eats this ill formed C program does not make it C++. This is C code and C question and author even uses `struct foobar foo;` so what makes this C++? Header naming?

Comment: @LeviX `strncpy(foo.field1, "1234567890", sizeof(foo.field1));`  -- Won't this lead to a buffer overrun?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie no it will lead to non null terminated char array

Comment: Just a note that this code just shows a warning on strncpy if compiled at VS2013 (no int problem).

Comment: Odd. under VS 2015 1_test.c craps out a buttload of errors because `using` is invalid in C. As expected, it happily includes the C++ headers because it knows where they are, but refuses to eat them. Not sure why GCC would allow this. Best guess is they're still C-conformant enough to get through.

Comment: The feature in `printf()` predates the existence of `size_t` as a type; that's why it uses `int` and not `size_t`.  (Standard I/O library was a late 70s feature — in 7th Edition UNIX, for example.  The `size_t` type wasn't a part of C — or the C support libraries — when the Standard I/O library was designed, so the type couldn't be used.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe your comment is the answer. No, there is not currently a way to fix this problem without changing each instance of the warning.

Answer (score 2):

Proper solution would be:

```
std::cout << std::string( foo.field1, sizeof( foo.field1 ) );
```

this would output what you desire and no warnings generated. But better solution fo course would be to use `std::string` in `struct foobar`

Answer (score 0):

You always have the unfun but sometimes the best solution to wrap in a macro

```
#define INT_SIZEOF( x ) static_cast< int >( sizeof( (x) ) )

printf("[%.*s]", INT_SIZEOF(foo.field1), foo.field1);
```

If your codebase is allergic to macros, you can do a simple syntactical wrapper for the `static_cast`, like this

```
int AsInt(size_t n) { return static_cast<int>( n ) }
printf("[%.*s]", AsInt(sizeof(foo.field1)), foo.field1);
```

As discussed in the comments, this solution can only take a size value, and therefore requires a separate `sizeof` operator. Plus, you lose any chance at a compile-time error checking if `sizeof` does not return a value that fits in an integer ( very unlikely though ).

Note that in both cases, your code is still ugly, but at least one is shorter and notifies the reader that something ugly is going on.

Finally, another possible decent alternative.

```
// constexpr is optional, you simply won't be able to use it in as many places if you don't use it
template<typename T> constexpr int intSizeof( T = T{} /*replace with () if necessary*/ ) 
{ 
    return static_cast<int>( sizeof( T ) ); 
}

printf("[%.*s]", intSizeof<decltype(foo.field1)>(), foo.field1);
```

This solution is definitely more C++ and more modern, at no real cost

Comment: How would this ever be the "best solution"? What does a macro do here that a function couldn't?

Comment: @CodyGray Evaluate at compile-time. Plus, the macro can take both types and expressions, while a function or a typetrait can only take either of them. (Yes, functions and typetraits can also evaluate a compile time in certain conditions )

Comment: If you are using a compiler that is incapable of inlining a function containing a static cast and a sizeof operator, then you should basically just give up. You aren't using the macro to pass a type here, you're using it to pass a value, so I don't see how that applies...?

Comment: I am not passing it a type in the current use case, but there might be more use cases. Still, I can still show your solution, it's just not much better.

Comment: @KABoissonneault you can pass type to a template function

Comment: @Slava I can, but if the function does not overload on the parameter, it won't work, because of how templated functions are instantiated (ie: they will be something like `int foo() { return sizeof(T); }`), which the linker won't like

Comment: `template <typename T> convertSizeof( size_t st ) { return static_cast<T>( st ); }` works fine

Comment: @Slava I don't think we were talking about the same thing. The point of passing a type to a function was to evaluate the `sizeof` inside the function instead of leaving the responsibility to the caller. After all, my initial was to write a "new `sizeof` operator" that could do the job of `sizeof` but return an int instead

Comment: OK, sorry  I missunderstood you: `template<typename T> constexpr int intSizeof( T ) { return static_cast<int>( sizeof( T = T{} ); }`